# Removing of multi line comments while preserving the line numbers

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh

I am using this to remove the multiline comments.

```
awk '/^--/ {next} /^\/\*/ && /\*\/$/{next} /^\/\*/{c=1;next} /\*\/$/{c=0;next} !c{FS="--|\/\*";a=$1;FS="\\*\\/";a=a$2;$0=a;print}' filename
```

Input is like this

```
aaaaaaa
/*bbbbb*/
ccccccc
/*bbbbb
bbbbbb*/
ddddd
```

I want it to be like

```
aaaaaaa 

ccccccc


dddddd
```

but im getting

```
aaaaaaa
ccccccc
ddddddd
```

Can anyone pls help me ....

Thanks

Comment: awk '/^--/ {next} /^\/\*/ && /\*\/$/{next} /^\/\*/{c=1;next} /\*\/$/{c=0;next} !c{FS="--|\/\*";a=$1;FS="\\*\\/";a=a$2;$0=a;print}' filename This is also having the same problem. It is removing the lines as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` may be the way to go:

```
awk '/\/\*|\*\// {$0=""}1' file
aaaaaaa

ccccccc


ddddd
```

It just replace line with `/*` or `*/` with nothing.

---

If the `bbbbbb` goes over more than one start/stop line, like this:

```
cat file
aaaaaaa
/*bbbbb*/
ccccccc
/*bbbbb
bbbbbb
bbbbbb*/
ddddd
```

And you would like to remove all from `/*` to `*/` and not only line with these tags:

```
awk '/^\/\*/ {f=1} {print f?"":$0} /\*\/$/ {f=0}' file
aaaaaaa

ccccccc



ddddd
```

Comment: can you pls explain the statement ... @Jotne

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes several assumptions about how comments are formatted.  I am going to assume that your assumptions are correct for your code and just supply the missing blank lines:

```
$ awk '/^--/ {next} /^\/\*/ && /\*\/$/{print ""; next} /^\/\*/{c=1;print "";next} /\*\/$/{c=0;print "";next} !c '  filename
aaaaaaa

ccccccc


ddddd
```

Comment: what if I use this. I tried but im having the same problems man. :( awk '/^--/ {next} /^\/\*/ && /\*\/$/{next} /^\/\*/{c=1;next} /\*\/$/{c=0;next} !c{FS="--|\/\*";a=$1;FS="\\*\\/";a=a$2;$0=a;print}' cut_file_name_temp_1

Comment: thnx man. I missed the blank lines while preparing the code..:) cheers